# vim caught deadly signal SEGV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, crash, zsh

While using vim with pathogen and rails.vim it sometimes crashes vim. This is my console log file for the crash. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
Process:         vim [16620]
Path:            /usr/bin/vim
Identifier:      vim
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  zsh [961]

Date/Time:       2011-08-31 08:20:25.727 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J869)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff832af5d6 __kill + 10
1   vim                             0x0000000100118943 0x100000000 + 1149251
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff832c166a _sigtramp + 26
3   vim                             0x00000001000249a2 0x100000000 + 149922
4   vim                             0x00000001000249ef 0x100000000 + 149999
5   vim                             0x00000001000249ef 0x100000000 + 149999
6   vim                             0x0000000100024a1c 0x100000000 + 150044
7   vim                             0x00000001000249ef 0x100000000 + 149999
8   vim                             0x000000010002554c 0x100000000 + 152908
9   vim                             0x0000000100118b75 0x100000000 + 1149813
10  vim                             0x000000010010c138 0x100000000 + 1098040
11  vim                             0x0000000100069900 0x100000000 + 432384
12  vim                             0x000000010006cf45 0x100000000 + 446277
13  vim                             0x000000010006d1a3 0x100000000 + 446883
14  vim                             0x000000010006d5d6 0x100000000 + 447958
15  vim                             0x00000001000a475c 0x100000000 + 673628
16  vim                             0x0000000100075bb8 0x100000000 + 482232
17  vim                             0x0000000100077e22 0x100000000 + 491042
18  vim                             0x0000000100000978 0x100000000 + 2424

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000002  rcx: 0x00000001001cdbc8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00000000000040ec  rsi: 0x000000000000000b  rbp: 0x00000001001cdbe0  rsp: 0x00000001001cdbc8
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x00007fff7073fbc0  r10: 0x00007fff832b1552  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000000029  r13: 0x000000000000007c  r14: 0x000000000000007c  r15: 0x0000000000000044
  rip: 0x00007fff832af5d6  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x0000000101185000

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100155fef +vim ??? (???) <F8247F1F-4D43-963A-D218-3D0E8ECFF899> /usr/bin/vim
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???) <B536F2F1-9DF1-3B6C-1C2C-9075EA219A06> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff83260000 -     0x7fff83421fff  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.10 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9BAEB2F2-B485-6349-E1AB-637FE12EE770> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff85845000 -     0x7fff85849ff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff85dcb000 -     0x7fff85e0afef  libncurses.5.4.dylib 5.4.0 (compatibility 5.4.0) <E1F34D53-3D62-78C0-CAD8-8AD22C110A9E> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
    0x7fff87ca5000 -     0x7fff87d9dff7  libiconv.2.dylib 7.0.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <E0683DF0-8180-58A2-BA49-511111D4F36E> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fffffe00000 -     0x7fffffe01fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <9BAEB2F2-B485-6349-E1AB-637FE12EE770> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Comment: It might be worth checking if `vim --version` shows that vim was compiled with the same verison of Ruby shown by `:!ruby --version` from within vim.

Comment: @Paul I am using rvm. So my `:!ruby --version` shows as 1.9.2 while vim's ruby version is the system ruby...I believe '1.8'. I've tried starting up vim with `:!ruby --version' at 1.8 but then I am unable to `bundle exec ...` to run anything. It errors out.

Comment: I use RVM, and used Homebrew to build MacVim, which linked it against RVM's Ruby 1.9.2. Excerpt from `mvim --version`: `Compilation: ... -lruby.1.9.1 -lobjc -L/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180-apalmblad/lib`

Comment: @Paul I will try to match up vim's compiled ruby and the ruby that's running from rvm. Any idea why this mismatch might causes problems?

Comment: Because you mentioned rails.vim and because I've had segfaults caused by ruby-based vim plugins (Hammer.vim and Command-T.vim) when the ruby versions mismatch. Not a certain solution, just worth looking into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask brew to compile macvim with debugging flag set, then run it under a debugger so that when it crashes you can ask the debugger to print the stack trace so that you can see which source code line is trying to access deallocated memory area which causes the SIGSEGV exception.

If you managed to get it that far then see if you can fix the error and submit a patch to the vim-dev list and feel good about it for a week :) good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Vim sometime will crash. If your ruby code are not well format.

```
process(:hello => 'world', :foo => 'bar')
```

You should not write as:

```
process(:hello => 'world', 
                         :foo => 'bar')
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Vim shouldn't crash when you write your function args on two lines! If you've found a bug and can reproduce it, report it so that it can be fixed.

Comment: my vim version is 7.4, i use it to write ruby. When i format my code like i posted, it will crash, but when the second line is format with two space, vim work fine. but i don't know that's why.

Comment: it's a bug in some plugin. probably rails.vim or some plugin that does ruby syntax highlighting.

running vim -u NONE -U NONE won't load plugins and allow you to test this.

Comment: @dwaynemac Thank you. I try it again. It is cause by code in .vimrc "syntax on
", if i turn off this every thing is ok! But let me puzzled, vim will  only crash when the file has many lines(maybe 500) and with code(like above) in the middle of the file(head or bottom is ok!).

Answer (score 0):

In my case vim stopped working after mavericks installation. I tracked it down to an issue with rvm, which was also on my system. 'vim -u NONE' ran fine. There were many suggestions about recompiling command-T, a vim plugin, but doing so didn't fix the problem for me. I ended using '**rvm implode**' to remove rvm altogether. Then '**brew uninstall vim && brew install vim**'. This fixed vim, and also fixed macvim, which was not opening windows unlessed launched from the console with 'mvim'. Therefore, there is some incompatibility with mavericks and rvm, which causes problems with vim.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of researching following different threads turns out there may be a ton of reasons causing vim to crash and getting that error message(not surprising!). But in my particular case after running it in verbose mode I realized there were stuff in my ~/.vimrc file that vim crashed because of. So very easily after removing my ~/.vimrc everything went back to normal and no more crashing. Just make sure you keep a back-up of it before removing in case you have customized your vim.